# Efficiency Query about LinkedLists

Tags: java

I was solving this question and even though I found a solution I was confused about one aspect.

```
//  * Definition for singly-linked list.
//  * public class ListNode {
//  *     int val;
//  *     ListNode next;
//  *     ListNode() {}
//  *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
//  *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
//  * }
//  */

class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode head = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode dummy = head;
        int sum = 0;
        int carry = 0;

        while(l1 != null || l2 != null){
            // check if either is not null
            // used to handle cases where one input linkedlist might be empty or shorter than other
            // if condition is true, x = l1.val else x = 0
            int x = (l1 != null) ? l1.val : 0;
            int y = (l2 != null) ? l2.val : 0;

            sum = carry + x + y;
            dummy.next = new ListNode(sum % 10)

            // carry = sum/10;
            carry = (sum >= 10) ? 1 : 0;
            
            if(l1 != null){
                l1 = l1.next;
            }

            if(l2 != null){
                l2 = l2.next;
            }

            dummy = dummy.next;
        }

        if(carry == 1){
            dummy.next = new ListNode(carry);
        }

        return head.next;
    }
}
```

I found that carry = (sum >= 10) ? 1 : 0 works better than carry = sum/10.
By works better I mean it makes my code way more efficient and that is the only change I made. Anyone understand why that might be the case.

Comment: How did you measure the execution time to arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: Ohh i was solving this on leetcode and it tells you that when you submit so.

Comment: Ignore that. Leetcode does not give you accurate timings.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this is that the comparison is much faster operation than division. The complexities of various operations are nicely stated in this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations) page. Also the complexity of division algorithm depends on the method which is used by compiler to perform the division. But in any way comparison is cheaper operation than division in terms of complexity.

Comment: Division by a constant can be and is heavily optimized by the jit compiler. The end result does not even do a division, instead it's reduced to a multiplication and some cheaper operation. Branch prediction miss on the other hand, is very expensive. It's really not that clear which method will be faster in practice. Most likely the op hasn't measured the running time correctly. By the it sounds like you've confused Java with JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've made it more generalized now. Still, the comparison operation is cheaper op in terms of cpu cycles than division. Although we cannot compare these operations because both are used for doing different operations. Multiplication vs division is a suitable choice for comparison as they are interrelated. Taking into consideration the division by constant, yes it does change the complexity out there. But take into consideration, the comparison with constant number also.

Comment: Thank you guys, amazing clarification.

Comment: Actually guys, its weird but I was just trying to run and Leetcode gives different runtimes on every run.